# Iterate through timer then get their names

Tags: vb.net, timer

Yes, by spending time on research I am aware that

> A Timer is a Component not a Control so it will not be located in the
>   Control Collection. This is a case where it is probably better to not
>   use a common button click handler since it is not simplifying
>   anything. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646686/find-timers-by-name))

But, is there anything that I can do to pass my current situation?

What I want is whenever a user clicks a button (I have many buttons) it will determine if the status of that button is `Start` or `Stop` then if it is `stop` it should `start`.

Stop and Start correspond to the timer, the number of buttons I have corresponds to the number of timers I have.

I can easily linked them by creating a function like this

```
Function isBTNStatusEnabled(sender As Object) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Dim btnStatus As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim btnStatusNumber As String = btnStatus.Name.Substring(btnStatus.Name.Length - 1)

    Console.WriteLine("Found the " & btnStatus.Name)
    If btnStatus.Text = "Start" Then
        btnStatus.Text = "Stop"
        result = True
        btnStatus.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else
        btnStatus.Text = "Start"
        result = False
        btnStatus.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
    End If

    For Each frmTesterObjects As Object In Me.components.Components
        If TypeOf frmTesterObjects Is Timer And DirectCast(frmTesterObjects, Timer).Tag.ToString = "tmrString" & btnStatusNumber Then
            'what to do 
            Console.WriteLine("Timer name: " & DirectCast(frmTesterObjects, Timer).Tag.ToString)
        End If
    Next frmTesterObjects

    Return result
End Function
```

My problem is this part of code

```
 If TypeOf frmTesterObjects Is Timer And DirectCast(frmTesterObjects, Timer).Tag.ToString = "tmrString" & btnStatusNumber Then
   Console.WriteLine("Timer name: " & DirectCast(frmTesterObjects, Timer).Tag.ToString)
 End If
```

I am trying to get the name of the timer by iterating through all objects in my forms. I can easily group all of the objects by properly naming them, for example in `set 1` I have `btnStatus1` and `tmrString1` then in `set 2` I have `btnStatus2` and `tmrString2`, only the last string which is a number changes.

Comment: do you want to use `Tag` instead?

Comment: If `Tag` will help me to get the name of the timer it's okay. :) In my code, I'm just trying to use the `Tag` because someone suggested it.

Comment: In your case, your code looks fine using `Tag`. All you have to do now is change the `Tag` of your timers individually.

Comment: Could you please post an answer?

Comment: Derive your own class from Button, add a property to store the timer.

Comment: @CaryBondoc - Can you tell me what the actual task that you're trying to do with the buttons and timers? What's the functionality you're trying to implement?

Comment: I am trying to create an automated tester, this app will send serial command every `n` seconds, I've created 8 sets of it, each set is consist of `textbox` to type what command I want to send, `button` to enable or disable the timer, then a `numeric updown` to configure the interval of timer, I also have `radiobutton` so I can choose what comport to use .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've almost always found that searching for components by name at run-time will eventually fail if you continue to maintain/modify the form. It is far better, in my opinion, to make sure you have a compile-time check.

I would do this code instead:

```
Function isBTNStatusEnabled(sender As Object) As Boolean

    Dim button2Timer = New Dictionary(Of Button, Timer) From
        {{Button1, Timer1}, {Button2, Timer2}, {Button3, Timer3}}

    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Dim btnStatus As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    Console.WriteLine("Found the " & btnStatus.Name)
    If btnStatus.Text = "Start" Then
        btnStatus.Text = "Stop"
        result = True
        btnStatus.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else
        btnStatus.Text = "Start"
        result = False
        btnStatus.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("Timer name: " & button2Timer(btnStatus).Tag.ToString())

    Return result

End Function
```

The `Dictionary(Of Button, Timer)` hard-codes the mapping in so that there is no need to search for the `Timer`. This also alleviates the need to actually name and tag the buttons and timers.

---

Just for the fun of it I have had a go at implementing your full solution based on your answer to my comment on the question. Here it is:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim parts =
    {
        New With {.Button = Button1, .NumericUpDown = NumericUpDown1, .TextBox = TextBox1, .Port = 1},
        New With {.Button = Button2, .NumericUpDown = NumericUpDown2, .TextBox = TextBox2, .Port = 2},
        New With {.Button = Button3, .NumericUpDown = NumericUpDown3, .TextBox = TextBox3, .Port = 3}
    }

    Dim query =
        From p In parts
        Select
            Observable _
                .FromEventPattern(Sub(h) AddHandler p.Button.Click, h, Sub(h) RemoveHandler p.Button.Click, h) _
                .ObserveOn(Me) _
                .Do(Sub(ep)
                        Dim start = p.Button.Text = "Start"
                        p.Button.Text = If(start, "Stop", "Start")
                        p.Button.BackColor = If(start, Color.Red, SystemColors.Control)
                        p.NumericUpDown.Enabled = Not start
                        p.TextBox.Enabled = Not start
                    End Sub) _
                .Select(Function(ep) _
                    Observable _
                        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(p.NumericUpDown.Value)) _
                        .Select(Function(n) New With {p.TextBox.Text, p.Port}) _
                        .TakeWhile(Function(x) p.Button.Text = "Stop")) _
                .Switch()

    query _
        .Merge() _
        .ObserveOn(Me) _
        .Subscribe(
            Sub(x)
                TextBox4.Text = TextBox4.Text + String.Format("Text ""{0}"" on Port ""{1}""{2}", x.Text, x.Port, Environment.NewLine)
            End Sub)

End Sub
```

I've used Microsoft's Reactive Framework for all of the event handling and timers. You just need to NuGet "Rx-WinForms" into your app to use it.

You'll see that `parts` contains a list of the button, numeric up/down, text box and a port number.

`query` takes these parts and creates handlers for the button clicks. Based on the text within the button it starts timers based on the numeric up/down controls and text boxes. Query simply produces a stream of values in the form of `{ .Text = "Foo", .Port = 1 }`. `query` also uses a `.Do(...)` operator to update the UI while the timers are running.

Finally the `.Subscribe(...)` code takes these values, and, in my app, adds them to a text box on the form so that I can see all the output.

Here's an example of the form as I was using it:

[image: form]

I hope this is of interest.

Comment: So amazing! Thank you so much! Yes, this is of my interest! I am now studying the nuget.

Comment: It's now working! My thank you is not enough to express my gratitude. A code that is so great!

Answer (score 1):

I've just simplified your code. Here it is:

```
   For Each x In Me.components.Components.OfType(Of Timer)()
        If x.Tag = "tmrString" & btnStatusNumber Then
            Console.WriteLine("Timer name: " & x.Tag)
        End If
    Next
```

All you have to do now is match the `Tag` of each `Timer` corresponding to its `Name`.

Comment: Oh, `All you have to do now is match the Tag of each Timer corresponding to its Name.` this is the part that is unclear to me. Sorry, could you provide an example with that?

Comment: Are your `timers` created at `design-time`?

Comment: Ahhm, not sure? I drag and drop them. Rename each of them

Comment: On `design-time`, click each `timer`, you can see its `properties`, there is a `Tag`. Change it same to the name of your `timer`.

Comment: Yes, this is working. Thanks! I've encountered an error. The cause of it is because I have null or empty timer1.tag property, I just added this code to handle it `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(frmTesterObjects.Tag.ToString) = False Then (do the comparison of timer tag)`

Comment: Oh, good to know. Sorry for the error, I haven't tested that code. Happy coding pre :)